# How to remove this broken bathtub cartridge

Tags: bathtub

I have seen several MOEN-specific videos where there is a clip that needs to be removed. This one looks different:

[image]

The other part of the cartridge:

[image]

How do I remove this cartridge? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like there are 6 flats on the brass nut that you could put a Cresent wrench on to unscrew the nut. That might release the rest of the cartridge. I'd wait for a more expert opinion, though.

Comment: @FreeMan while waiting, take look at my answers to your question

Comment: Use a small but long self drilling screw

Comment: @FreeMan that was my guess as well. I'll wait as suggested though - thanks :)

Comment: @knowitall does the brass nut need to be removed?

Comment: Remove the black cover pate and take a picture again, just guessing, the large brass nut is holding the whole valve assmebly, so it might not have to be removed.